Logical mistake in PL attribution
We are attributing the PnL of a single stock option to risk factors, solving the PLA problem. We have desk quotes $MV(T-1), MV(T)$, and $PnL_{T}=MV(T)-MV(T-1)$. We associate $MV$'s to $\sigma_{iv}^{T-1}, \sigma_{iv}^{T}$, thus $MV(t)=f(\sigma_{iv}^t;t)$ for the appropriate pricing function $f$ (suppose even that is the Black-Scholes formula).
Then we attribute $PnL_{T}$ to $\sigma_{iv}$ change (particularly):
$$
PnL_{T}\approx\Delta_{T-1}(S_T-S_{T-1})+\frac{1}{2}\Gamma_{T-1}(S_T-S_{T-1})^2+Vega_{T-1}(\sigma_{iv}^{T}-\sigma_{iv}^{T-1})+\theta_{T-1}
$$
We explain PnL via the change in implied vol, computed wrt to MV change (that is explained via PnL again). That is a logical mistake, isn't it?

Not really, as you are missing second order effects of vol, such as volga etc.
